# CakePHP login redirects users back to login page (IE11 and Edge)

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have a CakePHP application (v 2.7), which contains a fairly standard login element using the Auth component. This works fine for the majority of users, however, a handful of users are reporting that they cannot sign in - when they attempt to do so they are redirected back to the login page, with no error message.

I have built some logging in to the site to check what is happening and it seems that the login is going through fine (everything in my login action is logged working as desired) until they hit the redirect part of the code, then they are not redirected to the intended page.

All the users who are having problems seem to be coming to the site through the same company network - not sure if that's of relevance or not! However, all have cookies enabled (I have added a script to display an error if they are not enabled).

I have tested the site in IE11, Edge 11, 12 + 13 (the browsers that users appear to be having issues with) but cannot replicate the issue, regardless of the security settings on the browser.

Could this issue be related to settings in the network that the users are accessing the site from? Are there any settings I should try to get them to check? Sorry - I'm pretty stumped by this one, as I just cannot replicate it, any pointers towards the questions I should be asking would be useful.

The relevant sections of my code are below. If there are any bits that would be helpful please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**In the AppController (components)**

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Cookie',
    'Security' => array(
        'csrfExpires' => '+300 minutes',
        'csrfUseOnce' => false
    ),
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'course_sections', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'website_pages', 'action' => 'view', 'home', 'admin' => false),
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'all' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.is_archived' => 0, 'Client.is_active' => 1),
                'contain' => array('UserGroup'),
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            ),
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            )
        )
    ),
    'Acl'
);
```

**In the UsersController**

```
public function login(){

    // If user has submitted the form
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            $this->log('Successfully logged in. Cookie Status: ' . $this->request->data['User']['cookies'], $this->Auth->user('public_id'));

            // Redirect
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());

        } else {

            // Log failed login attempt
            $this->log('Unsusccessful login attempt using email: ' . $this->request->data['User']['email'], 'nosuccess');

            $this->Session->setFlash($this->FlashMessage->translateFlash('invalid_login', false));
        }

    }

}
```

I am using database backed sessions, but the issue is the same whether using these or PHP ones.